# CSS unordered list with dotted full block width underline

Tags: css

How i can make an ordered list like the one in the screenshot?
What is important is to have a full width dotted underline per item.

Thank you
[Sample ordered list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JZNw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see and run the code snippets for your desire output.

```css
ul > li {
  color: grey;
  border-bottom: thin dashed grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Terms of Use </li>
  <li> Privacy Policy </li>
</ul>
```

Updated with class `mylist`

```css
ul.mylist > li {
  color: grey;
  border-bottom: thin dashed grey;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mylist">
  <li> Terms of Use </li>
  <li> Privacy Policy </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. As I don't want to have this style global, do I need to change it (eg) to ul.mylist > li.mylist and then ul class="mylist" etc?

Comment: I have updated the usage to add in class `mylist` for `<ul>`. Basically, you don't need to add class `mylist` to `<li>`

Answer (score 2):

Use a unordered list (`<ul>`) in combination with `border-bottom`, like this:

```css
li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed gray
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add border-bottom to each li item.

```css
ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

Furthermore, you can add a bit of padding:

```css
ul li {
  padding: 1em 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, add dotted border.

```css
ul li{
  border-bottom: dotted 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>term of use</li>
  <li>Privecy Policy</li>
  <li>Refund Policy</li>
</ul>
```